The code hangs my current session. How do I dispose the form and end the Runspace and Powershell session?
Everything seems ito work correctly in my code except that I cannot seem to get the correct sequence of statements to close a form, the Runspace, and the Powershell session. The code creates the runspace, creates the form, loads the Gif (a dog chasing his tail) asynchronously allows the GET-CHILDITEM command to run, returns control to the main form but seem to hang on the line:
$Powershell.EndInvoke($Handle)

...because I never see the message "Did I Get this far" nor the write-host results fof the Foreach loop.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing    
Clear-Host
$Gif_Form = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Gif_Form.One = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Runspace = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$Runspace.Open()
$Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Gif_Form',$Gif_Form)
$Powershell = [Powershell]::Create()
$Powershell.Runspace = $Runspace
$Powershell.AddScript(
{ 
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing      

 $Gif_Form.One = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
 $Gif_Form.One.Text = "PLEASE WAIT..."
 $Gif_Form.One.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1200,100)
 $Gif_Form.One.StartPosition = "Manual"
 $Gif_Form.One.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(166,160)
 $Gif_Form.One.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
 $Gif_Form.One.BackColor = "RED"
 $Gif_Form.One.ControlBox = $FALSE
 $Gif_Form.One.Enabled = $TRUE
 $Gif_Form.One.Add_Shown({$Gif_FORM.Activate()})

 $PictureBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
 $PictureBox.LoadAsync("G:\Dog Chasing Tail.gif")
 $PictureBox.BackColor = "RED"
 $PictureBox.SizeMode = "AutoSize"
 $Picturebox.Visible = $TRUE
 $X = 25
 $Y = 10
 $Picturebox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($X,$Y)
 $Gif_Form.One.controls.add($PictureBox)
 
 $Gif_Form.One.Visible=$FALSE
 $Gif_Form.One.ShowDialog()
})
$Handle = $Powershell.BeginInvoke() 
Write-Host "Starting GET-ChildItem command..."
$Folders = $Null
#---------------------------------------------------------#
$Folders = Get-Childitem -Path C:\  `
                         -Directory `
                         -Recurse   `
                         -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#---------------------------------------------------------#
# Test the automatic variable $? to see if the previous   #
# Command has completed successfully.  If $? is equal to  #
# $TRUE, then the command completed successfully.         #
#---------------------------------------------------------#
Write-Host "...Get-ChildItem is done."
#---------------------------------------------------------#
# Get rid of the Powershell session and runspace          #
# value was computed.                                     #
#---------------------------------------------------------#
$Gif_Form.One.Dispose()
$Powershell.EndInvoke($Handle)
Write-Host "Did I get this far?"
$RunSpace.Close()
$Powershell.Dispose()
Foreach ($PSItem in $Folders) 
{
 Write-Host $PsItem.Name -BackgroundColor Black `
                         -ForegroundColor Green
}

So is it better if I rewite the code like this...
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing  
Clear-Host
$Gif_Form = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Gif_Form.One = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Gif_Form.One.Text = "PLEASE WAIT..."
$Gif_Form.One.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1200,100)
$Gif_Form.One.StartPosition = "Manual"
$Gif_Form.One.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(166,160)
$Gif_Form.One.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Gif_Form.One.BackColor = "RED"
$Gif_Form.One.ControlBox = $FALSE
$Gif_Form.One.Enabled = $TRUE

$PictureBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox.Load("G:\MyFunctions\Dog Chasing Tail.gif")
$PictureBox.BackColor = "RED"
$PictureBox.SizeMode = "AutoSize"
$Picturebox.Visible = $TRUE
$Picturebox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(25,10)
$Gif_Form.One.Controls.add($PictureBox)

$Runspace = [Runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$Runspace.Open()
$Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Gif_Form',$Gif_Form)
$Powershell = [Powershell]::Create()
$Powershell.Runspace = $Runspace
$Powershell.AddScript(
{ 
 $Gif_Form.One.Visible=$FALSE
 $Gif_Form.One.Showdialog()
})
$Handle = $Powershell.BeginInvoke()

$Folders = $Null
#---------------------------------------------------------#
Write-Host "Starting GET-ChildItem command..."
$Folders = Get-Childitem -Path C:\  `
                         -Directory `
                         -Recurse   `
                         -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "...Get-ChildItem is done."
#---------------------------------------------------------#
# Get rid of the Powershell session and runspace          #
# value was computed.                                     #
#---------------------------------------------------------#
$Gif_Form.One.Close()
$Gif_Form.One.Dispose()
$Powershell.EndInvoke($Handle)
$RunSpace.Close()
$Powershell.Dispose()
Foreach ($PSItem in $Folders) 
{
 Write-Host $PsItem.Name -BackgroundColor Black `
                         -ForegroundColor Green
}

Because this worked for me.


I suspect it's something to do with the message loop on the winform / application not ending properly if the form is shown modally (i.e.  usingShowDIalog()) and then Disposed - if you invoke $Gif_Form.One.Show() instead of $Gif_Form.One.ShowDialog() it seems to work fine. Alternatively, calling $Gif_Form.One.Close() before $Gif_Form.One.Dispose() seems to work as well...

$Gif_Form.One.Close()
$Gif_Form.One.Dispose
$Powershell.EndInvoke($Handle)
$RunSpace.Close()
$Powershell.Dispose() ...this is what worked for me,  Thank you so much and God Bless you for taking the time to respond!

@mclayton definitely the issue is disposing the form while showing dialog. I couldn't find anything documented reg. not disposing the form from a different thread. an easier way to repro the issue: $form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new(); Start-ThreadJob { Start-Sleep 5; ($using:form).Dispose() }; $form.ShowDialog(). You should def. post the answer. Close() works perfect

@SantiagoSquarzon - Done. I did a bit more experimenting and using Invoke to call Dispose in the OP's code also fixes the issue - I think that's the "fix" whereas my suggestion above was more luck than judgement :-)

@mclayton  -  I posted a second version of the code that I hope creates and disposes the form in the same routine. Is this better and what you mean?

So the thing about Windows Forms is they're fickle about what thread code is executed on - I don't pretend to understand all the nitty gritty details of why, but as a rule of thumb you should only call methods on forms and controls on the thread they were created on (called the UI thread) - see How to make thread-safe calls to controls for more details where it says:

It's unsafe to call a control directly from a thread that didn't create it.

Your code is not calling methods (e.g. Dispose) on the thread that created the form because you're creating the form inside the $Powershell.BeginInvoke()'s thread and calling $Gif_Form.One.Dispose() from your main script thread. Unfortunately your code is triggering a race condition / thread synchronisation (/ hand-waving) issue that the rule of thumb is designed to avoid, and your script is hanging as a result.
To help with this, WinForms Forms and Controls have a couple of helper methods:

Invoke
Executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

and

InvokeRequired
Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method when making method calls to the control because the caller is on a different thread than the one the control was created on.

You can use them like this in PowerShell:
$sb = { $form.Dispose(); }
if ($form.InvokeRequired)
{
    # invoke $sb on the form's UI thread
    $form.Invoke($sb)
}
else
{
    # we're already running on the form's UI thread so just invoke the scriptblock
    $sb.Invoke();
}

In your example you already know you need to use Invoke because you're on a different thread so you can change it to this and it'll just work:
$Gif_Form.One.Invoke(
    { $Gif_Form.One.Dispose() }
)

Similarly, with @SantiagoSquarzon's example in comments:
$form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new();

Start-ThreadJob {
    Start-Sleep 5;
    ($using:form).Dispose()
};

$form.ShowDialog()

where the form is created in the main script thread, we need to Invoke calls inside the ThreadJob...
Start-ThreadJob {
    Start-Sleep 5;
    ($using:form).Invoke(
        { ($using:form).Dispose(); }
    );
};

... and it'll run through to completion.

Note - my original suggestions in comments to use one of the following:

$Gif_Form.One.Show() instead of $Gif_Form.One.ShowDialog()
call $Gif_Form.One.Close() before $Gif_Form.One.Dispose()

were just lucky that they worked - they still violate the rule of thumb re calling Form and Control methods on the same thread as they were created, except that they just magically avoided the deadlock. The better fix is to use Invoke where required, or couple it with InvokeRequired to test what the appropriate way is to call it...

very nice reg. InvokeRequired and Invoke. Can't say I used them before :)

I think I might get what you are saying. maybe.

But when I run it I get the error: Cannot find an overload for "Invoke" and the argument count: "1".
At G:\StackOverflow.ps1:47 char:1

$Gif_Form.One.Invoke( { $Gif_Form.One.Dispose() } )

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest



#---------------------------------------------------------#
Delete this line...
$Handle = $Powershell.BeginInvoke()
#---------------------------------------------------------#
Insert this line...
#---------------------------------------------------------#
$Gif_Form.One.Invoke( { $Gif_Form.One.Dispose() } )

Delete these lines...
#$Gif_Form.One.Dispose()
#$Powershell.EndInvoke($Handle)

Sorry that I posted what I did after the Error message that I received.
